# How to delete rows which has nan or empty value in SPECIFIC column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has nan or empty cell in **specific column** for example column index 2.  unfortunately I don't have subset. I just have index. I want to **delete the rows** which has this features. in stackoverflow there are too many soluntions which are using subset

This is the dataframe for example:

12       125       36       45        665

15       212       12       65        62

65        9        **nan**     98      84

21       54        78         5       654

211       65        58        26       65

...

**output**:

12       125     36     45      665

15       212     12     65       62

21       54      78       5      654

211       65      58      26      65

Comment: Do you need `df.dropna()` ?

Comment: @  jezrael no it doesn't work for me.

Comment: and `df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).dropna()` working?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much for trying to help. I want to search according specific column. for example in column 3 row 25 it has nan or empty cell. then try to delete the entire row 25, but it should be according to Specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need test third column (with index=2) use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if `nan` is missing value `np.nan` or string `nan`:

```
idx = 2


df1 = df[df.iloc[:, idx].notna() & df.iloc[:, idx].ne('nan')]

#if no value is empty string or nan string or missing value NaN/None
#df1 = df[df.iloc[:, idx].notna() & ~df.iloc[:, idx].isin(['nan',''])]
print (df1)
     0    1     2   3    4
0   12  125  36.0  45  665
1   15  212  12.0  65   62
3   21   54  78.0   5  654
4  211   65  58.0  26   65
```

If `nan`s are missing values:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=df.columns[[idx]])
print (df1)
     0    1     2   3    4
0   12  125  36.0  45  665
1   15  212  12.0  65   62
3   21   54  78.0   5  654
4  211   65  58.0  26   65
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> there are too many soluntions which are using subset

but the way to do this would be

```
df[~df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I want to search according to specific column for example column 2 in row 35 has nan or empty cell. after find it delete the row 35.

Answer (score 0):

You can use notnull()

```
df = df.loc[df[df.columns[idx]].notnull()]
```